# Spring tool suite does not handle top level packages with more than 3 levels

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

When I created a new Spring MVC project (File/New/Project.../Spring/Spring Template Project/Spring MVC project) with name ch17 and top level package com.apress.prospring3.ch17 I found that the default home page was under /prospring3, the project's context root was prospring3, and the top level package under src/main/java was com/apress/prospring3. That is, ch17 was getting chopped off.

So I repeated the project creation but this time used a top level package with one less level. I used com.prospring3.ch17. This did what I wanted: the default home page was under /ch17, the project's context root was ch17, and the top level package contained all my names: com/prospring3/ch17.

I cannot find anything about this issue. Is there some setting I overlooked that would allow me to work with packages that are more than 3 levels deep? This caused me a good deal of grief because the book I am following routinely uses 4 level root packages.

Here are the details of my configuration:

- STS Version: 3.2.0.RELEASE
- STS Build Id: 201303060821
- Installed JRE: jdk1.7.0_21
- Server: VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.8

-Eric

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "homepage", but typically a Spring MVC project is deployed as a WAR, and the WAR is what drives where the "welcome" page is at and the "context" used in the URL.  The java class path has nothing to do with URLs, JSPs, or context.